# Getting column data from a certain pattern in Excel

Tags: python, excel

For example, I would like to get the latest login time which are successful for jack and peter based on the excel data.
[Excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBZoi.png)
I would like to get latest login date for jack and paul by comparing if the status is success. furthermore, I want to only want the latest login date by a user, like if john logs everyday on the month of February, I would like to keep only the latest success date that he had logged in. Is there any way I can do it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a way to bring these Excel data into Python?  If you give more information about what you have considered so far or any partial progress you have made, it will be easier for somebody to help you along.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel ('Excel_file.xlsx')
```

after that you can use it as pandas dataframe

```
df.loc[(df['Target']  == "Amy") & (df['Login'] == "Success")]
```

after that sort by date and print last one